# PHP Submitting form with base64 image causing chrome memory increase

Tags: javascript, forms

here is my code

Form:

```
<form action='/tests' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Upload Cover</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @if(isset($brand->cover->url))
                <img src="{{ $brand->cover->url }}" alt="" width="15%"
                     style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            @endif

            <div class="cover-editor">
                <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
                <div class="cropit-preview"></div>

                <div class="image-size-label">
                    Resize image
                </div>
                <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
                <textarea name="cover" class="cover" v-show="false"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I'm using this plugin http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/:

```
<script>
    $('.cover-editor').cropit({width: 640, height: 360, exportZoom: 3, maxZoom: 3});

    $('#form').on('submit', function () {

        $('.cover').val($('.cover-editor').cropit('export'));
    });
</script>
```

When submitting the form, my chrome memory usage suddenly spike from 100mb to 2gb.

Any solution?

Comment: What's the image size?

Comment: 261kb. 1920*1080px @DainisAbols

Comment: Does this happen only on chrome? What about other browsers?

Comment: @LukasMeine only happen on chrome. I've tried using FF. it stable at 300mb - 400mb

Comment: Welcome to Chrome and it's huge appetite for RAM.